# Elements of finite order of $\mathrm{PGL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-number-theory

For some research work, I need to know the classification of elements of finite order of $\mathrm{PGL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$, up to conjugation.

Since I essentially need $n\le 4$, I think that I can show it by hand, using cyclotomic extensions and Galois theory, but is there some work in the literature on this?

EDIT: Looking at the possible orders is essentially trivial in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$, by just looking at the cyclotomic polynomials. The conjugacy classes require a little more work but are easy exercises, at least in low dimension. For $\mathrm{PGL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$, the case of orders prime to $n$ follows essentially from the case of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$, the orders are more interesting.

Comment: there seems to be a lot known about finite subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$, cf. e.g. references in http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-12/S0002-9939-97-04283-4/S0002-9939-97-04283-4.pdf
E.g. each of them is conjugate to one in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Isn't this just a question about rational canonical form? The question is certainly easier for elements of finite order in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Q}),$ but even there, calculating the maximum possible order of an element of finite order in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$ is quite subtle.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: what's so subtle in $GL_n(Q)$? you need to list $L_n$, the set of all cyclotomic polynomials of degree $\le n$, then from $L_n$ you list $L'_n$, the set of all subsets of $L_n$ whose sum of degrees is $\le n$. For each $\{\Phi_{n_1},\dots,\Phi_{n_k}\}$ in $L'_n$, you get an element of order lcm$(n_1,\dots,n_k\}$ in $GL_n(Q)$. Of course I don't claim it's algorithmically efficient when $n$ is very large.

Comment: @Yves Cornulier: I just meant that that lcm is not so easy to explicitly evaluate, although theoretically, as you say, it is a formality.

Comment: @Jérémy: my guess is that a natural approach would be to start up to conjugation in $PGL_n(C)$, and then to understand when two elements in $PGL_n(Q)$ are conjugate over $C$ are conjugate over $Q$: since this problem is trivial in $GL_n$, one can expect it to we well encoded (in Galois cohomology?) in $PGL_n$.

Comment: There is a paper of Beauville on the case $PGL_2(K)$, arXiv:0909.3942. The paper deals with the classification of conjugacy classes of finite subgroups in general, but the methods are (as you mention) mostly Galois theory. There is only one subtlety related to classifying elements of order $n$ in $PGL_n(K)$. Conjugacy classes correspond to $n$-power residues in $K$, the only case that is not "combinatorial" using cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Thanks Yves for your suggestion, it is basically what I wanted to do. I am still wondering if this was not done somewhere already. Thanks for the reference on Beauville's paper, that I knewed but which does the case of dimension $2$ (but is rather trivial over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I do not see what you mean here. If $A$ is an element of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$ corresponding to an element of order $d$ in $\mathrm{PGL}$, then $A^d=\lambda I$ and $\det(A)^d=\lambda^n$. So if $d,n$ are coprime, then $\lambda$ is some $d$-th power and you can multiply $A$ by a scalar to assume that it is of finite order in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: @Jeremy: OK, I see what you mean.

Comment: Is it expected that the set of orders of finite order elements in $PGL_n(Q)$ is reduced to the (a priori smaller) set of orders of elements in $PGL_n(Q)$ that are images of elements of finite order in $GL_n(Q)$?

Comment: @JérémyBlanc: to motivate my previous question: your problem splits into two distinct problems: (1) determine possible orders of elements, and (2) classify conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups of a given possible order. Do you consider (1) as an issue or is it easy?

Comment: @Ycor Maybe I did not investigate enough, but $(1)$ does not seem so easy at first sight for elements not coming from elements of finite order of $\mathrm{GL}_n$. Note: the order of elements coming from elements of finite order of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ can be different: if $n=2$ the orders in $\mathrm{GL}_n$ are $1,2,3,4,6$ but in $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ are $1,2,3$. I do not know if the orders in $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ are always a subset of those of $\mathrm{GL}_n$.

Comment: This is not my question: my question is: is it true, given $n$ and $d$ that if $PGL_n(Q)$ has an element of order $d$, then $GL_n(Q)$ has an element of finite order whose image in $PGL_n(Q)$ has order $d$. For instance this is true for $n=2$.

Comment: Yes, good question. I do not know...

Comment: See E. C. Dade's paper, Illinois J. Math. 1965, Maximal Finite Subgroups of 4 by 4 integral matrices.

Answer (score 4):

I figured I'd write up the elementary observations here, since no one else has: If $g^k = \mathrm{Id}$ in $PGL_n$, then $g^k = a \mathrm{Id}$ in $GL_n$ for some nonzero $a$. So the minimal polynomial of $g$ divides $x^k-a$. Let $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_r$ be the factorization of $x^k-a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. We can use rational canonical form to write down a $\deg p_i \times \deg p_i$ matrix $g_i$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$) with characteristic polynomial $p_i$. Then, for any nonnnegative integers $a_i$ such that $\sum a_i \deg p_i = n$, we can take the block diagonal matrix whose entries are $a_i$ copies of $g_i$. Conversely, if $g^k = a$, we can break $g$ into blocks according to the irreducible factors of $x^k-a$.

So, what remains is to analyze the degrees of the $p_i$. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^k-a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $G$ be the Galois group. Write $\zeta$ for a primitive $k$-th root of $1$ and $\alpha$ for a chosen $k$-th root of $a$ inside $K$. Then every element of $G$ is of the form $\zeta^i \alpha \mapsto \zeta^{ui+v}$ for $u \in (\mathbb{Z}/k)^{\times}$ and $v \in \mathbb{Z}/k$. So $G$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/k)^{\times} \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/k)$. Also, $G$ surjects onto $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$, so, for every $u \in \mathbb{Z}/k^{\times}$, the group $G$ contains an element of the form $i \mapsto ui+v$. The problem is to describe the orbits of such a group on $\mathbb{Z}/k$.

For example, when $k=4$, then $G$ is a subgroup of $\{ \pm 1 \} \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/4)$. If it isn't the whole group (in which case $x^4-a$ is irreducible), then it is either the group generated by $i \mapsto -i$ (in which case $x^4-a$ factors as $(\mbox{linear}) (\mbox{linear})(\mbox{quadratic})$, like $x^4-1$), or the group generated by $i \mapsto -i+1$ (in which case $x^4-a$ factors as $(\mbox{quadratic}) (\mbox{quadratic})$, like $x^4+4=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$), or else $\{ \pm 1 \} \times 2 \mathbb{Z}/4$, in which case (in which case $x^4-a$ factors as $(\mbox{quadratic}) (\mbox{quadratic})$, like $x^4-4$).

At this point, it isn't clear what to do next, and the question is also a bit unfocused. Here are some (in my opinion) natural questions:

- Is is true that $x^k-a$ always has a factor of degree $\geq \phi(k)$? UPDATE: No. $x^8-16 = (x^2-2)(x^2+2)(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$, and $\phi(8) = 4$.
- For fixed $k$, what is the smallest $n$ for which $PGL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ has an element of order $k$? It is NOT $\phi(k)$: We can build elements of order $15$ in $GL_6$ as the direct sum of elements of orders $3$ and $5$ in $GL_2$ and $GL_4$, even though $\phi(15) = 8$.
- I don't have an example of a case where $PGL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ has an element of order $k$ but $GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ doesn't. I imagine such a thing exists, but it would be good to have an example.

Comment: For your Q2, I think it's sum over $p$ dividing $k$ of $\phi(p^r)$, where $r$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $k$, except if $p=2$ and $r=1$ in which case you can ignore that term. This is because you have to include each prime power, and multiplying them multiplies their $\phi$, but adding is always less than multiplying when you're multiplying things at least $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda^k=a$. Consider how the Galois group of the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\lambda$ acts on the roots. As David Speyer points out, this is a subgroup of $(\mathbb Z/k)^\times \ltimes (\mathbb Z/k)$. If this subgroup has a nontrivial intersection with $ (\mathbb Z/k)$, then there is a $l$ dividing $k$ sucht hat for any root $\lambda$ of the minimal polynomial, and $l$th root of unity $\mu$, $\mu \lambda$ is also a root.

So the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\lambda$ is $l$ times the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\lambda^l$. Now we may reduce to the case where the Galois group has trivial intersection with $\mathbb Z/k$.

Observation 1: In this case the Galois group is abelian, so the size of the orbit is the size of the Galois group, so the size of the orbit is at least $\phi$ of the order of the element. So no new orders of elements of $PGL_n(\mathbb Q)$ appear that aren't orders of elements of $GL_n(\mathbb Q)$.

Observation 2: If $k$ is odd, then there is some element of the form $x \to 2x+b$ in the Galois group. This has the unique fixed point $x=-b$. Because the Galois group is abelian, every other element fixes this point. So the $k$th roots of $a$ are some rational number times the $k$th roots of unity.

Full classification: Let $m \in (\mathbb Z/k)^\times$ be an element such that $m-1 \in 2 (\mathbb Z/k)^\times$. Then there is an element $x \to mx+b$ in the Galois group. If $b$ is even, then this element has two fixed points, the solutions to $(m-1)x+b=0$, so every other element either fixes or reverses those points. What this means is that there is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q$ fixed by the index $2$ subgroup of the Galois group that fixes those two points, and that those two points are of the form $q \sqrt{D}$ where $q$ is rational and $\sqrt{D}$ generates that quadratic extension. One can easily classify all sets of roots of this type.

I see my argument in the case $b$ odd doesn't actually work so I don't have a full classification.

Comment: You can avoid the case $b$ odd: Replacing $x^n-a$ by $x^{2n}-a^2$, we may assume that our equation has a real root. Choose that real root to call $\alpha$, then complex conjugation acts by $\zeta^x \alpha \mapsto \zeta{-x} \alpha$, and that puts you in the case $b$ even. At this point, I think I know everything that can happen when factoring $x^n-a$ (including fun things like $x^{10} - 5^5$) but I'm having trouble organizing it into a succinct answer. If you can, please go ahead.

Comment: PS: There is not always an orbit of size $\geq \phi(n)$. Check out $x^8-16$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the question is equivalent to classifying up to conjugacy in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Q}),$ those matrices $M$ which satisfy $M^{d} = \frac{u}{v}I,$ where $d$ is a positive integer, $u$ is a positive integer, $v$ is anon-zero  integer, ${\rm gcd}(u,v) = 1$ and neither $u$ nor $v$ is divisible by the $d$-th power of any prime, and furthermore, no lower power of $M$ is scalar. Then it becomes  a question of determining what the possible rational canonical forms for $M$ can be. Maschke's theorem still goes through in this situation, suitably interpreted, and the minimum polynomial of $M$ is multiplicity free. The possible factors for the characteristic polynomial of such an $M$ are easy to determine.

Comment: Yes, this is the natural start. By looking at the determinant you get $\det(M)^d=(u/v)^m$. If $m$ and $d$ are prime, you can then reduce to the case of elements of finite order of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$. The other cases are more interesting.

Answer (score -1):

See
https://math.temple.edu/~lorenz/papers/sizes/sizes.pdf

Look for
The Minkowski sequence

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that the text that you mention only gives orders of finite subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$, which is essentially trivial for cyclic groups.